# Loop though Firestore Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wish to loop though my Firestore DB to get the total distance from all my documents combines

[image: Firestore Image]

Im currently using this query to get the total number of documents

```
    firebaseDB.collection("journey").document(key).collection("journeys")
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            }
            else
            {
                var totalJourney = 0
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    totalJourney += 1
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                }
                print("totalJourney = \(totalJourney)");
                self.totalJourney.text = String(totalJourney)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure why you're getting downvotes as you started the question clearly, presented your structure and then the code you used. So I upvoted you - hopefully my answer will help.

Comment: Many thanks @Jay , It's rather frustrating getting downvoted with no explanation.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that you weren't very clear in what you're asking. So: what is the problem when you run this code? What happens when you step through it in a debugger? But honestly, I mostly agree with Jay, as that is easily fixable by just asking you in a comment. So I also counter-upvoted. Only two more and we're back to where we started. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll keep them tips in mind for any future questions! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't far off but there are a few things missing in your code - for example, reading the distance child in each node and summing those. Here's some example code that outputs the number of journeys and the total miles travelled.

My structure is a little shallower than yours, and I used a child node called 'miles' instead of distance but the concept is the same.

```
func readJourneys() {
    self.db.collection("journeys").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            let count = querySnapshot!.documents.count

            var totalMiles = 0
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                //let journeyId = document.documentID
                let miles = document.get("miles") as! Int
                totalMiles += miles
            }
            print("There were: \(count) journeys covering: \(totalMiles) miles")
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
There were: 3 journeys covering: 20 miles
```

Comment: I really appreciate your solution Jay, This works perfectly!