# List view populated with firebase query results problem SWIFT IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I'm trying to do a List that is populated with query results from Firebase Database

I've got constantly some problems and i have no clue what can i try to do next ive looked through internet to help me do this but found nothing, can you help me?

Thanks in Advance

Here is the code with errors

```
class BoatListViewContoller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var title = [""] // Here error is saying "Property 'title' with type '[String]' cannot override a property with type 'String?'"
    var lenght:Int?

    func readProducts(){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("products").getDocuments(){
            querySnapshot, err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.lenght = querySnapshot!.count
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                    self.title.append(document.data()["title"] as! String) // Here i got a error saying "No exact matches in call to subscript"
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lenght!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = title[indexPath]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 212/255, green: 255/255, blue: 241/255, alpha: 1)
        return cell
    }
    private var myTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad();
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height
        myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight))
        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 212/255, green: 255/255, blue: 241/255, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(myTableView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**First error:**

`UIViewController` already has a property named `title`:

`open var title: String?`

You just need to rename `var title = [""]` to `var titles = ["]`, or something different than `title`.

**Second error:**

You might try `document.get("title") as! String` (*borrowed the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54601354/3227743*), or you might try

```
let data = document.data()
let title = data["title"]
```

or

```
self.title.append((document.data())["title"] as! String)
```

**Miscellaneous:**

You would also need to call `myTableView.reloadData()` after parsing every document.

*Nitpick: `length` instead of `lenght`. Also, you actually don't need that since you could (should) just use titles.count instead.*

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable insights, my data is loading(it shows up in print) but not shows up in table view where do you recon im gonna need to put this reloadData() right now im wondering why

Comment: You should do that right after you are done with the parsing, after your for loop has ended.

Comment: OMG ITS FINALLY WORKING IM BOWING TO YOU MY SWIFT SENPAI